# Sublime Text 3, REPL. How to build script in single tab or same REPL window?

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

I'll get to the point. I've installed SublimeText 3 and i also installed SublimeREPL through Package Control, and I've basically set it up as I need it.

The main thing that is annoying me, is that each time I build a python script (CTRL+B), another REPL file/tab opens, despite the fact that I've already have one open.

[Screenshot of sublimeREPL build tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYXFV.png)

[image]

Is there an approach to configure to open and build in single tab?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following line in the "**repl_python_run**" command in SublimeREPL\config\Python\Main.sublime-menu, right before the "external_id": "python" argument:
`"view_id": "*REPL* [python]"`,
and then to change the line:

```
if view.id() == view_id
```

into:

```
if view.name() == view_id
```

in `SublimeREPL\sublimerepl.py.`

Comment: Thanks @Bodhi94 .This was the simple and most clear answer for the problem. It worked!

Answer (score 0):

No, that doens't works.
First of all you need to be attentive, and delete the space in between "*REPL* [python]", because all crashing, and the Run stop to work at all, and ctrl + b.
Second - even after this changes - nothing changes. Another REPL file/tab continue to open.